# How to pass value from one form into another's combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have two forms, "Info o vlasniku" and "Nova narudzba". When I click on button in form "Info o vlasniku" I want field ID_VU from that form to be set in a combobox called Narudzba.ID_VU in "Nova narudzba" form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your click event:

```
Forms![Nova narudzba]![Narudzba.ID_VU].Value = Me!ID_VU.Value
```

Try using control names without spaces and, indeed, without dots.